# Insert data into mysql table when field names is changed dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql

I was try this by using this code. used the while loop but there is no solutions.

```
$counter= 0;
  $result= $cid->query("SELECT ComName FROM catcom"); 
  echo $count=$result->num_rows;
  while ($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $field_value[] = $row;
      $counter++;
  }
```

Array store the name of the field `$field_value[]` is it possible to store data to data base, like this code if possible to how to write syntax.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $import="INSERT into  $field_value[] values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Field names in a relational database should not change dynamically.
You have to learn relational architecture and design your database to make its fields stay firmly on their places, not running like ants before rain.

Comment: Sir, i am changing the name and update new field.                                 '$sql = "ALTER TABLE commissions ADD $head_db_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL AFTER Comm_id";'                                                     and similar i am updating the field name                                                            query("UPDATE catcom SET ComName ='$head_db_name', ComFullName ='$head_name', cat_id ='$cat_value' WHERE CatComId = '$ComId'") == TRUE)

Comment: and it could be change any time by Update Field name.

Comment: Actually i want to store data by using the, Xls file and store into the database now , and every time the Xls file fields are changed, and according to file, DATA base field are changed, now tell me that how can i upload file ??